# Where is artifactory home directory?

Tags: artifactory

The [artifactory documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing%20on%20Linux%20Solaris%20or%20Mac%20OS#InstallingonLinuxSolarisorMacOS-TheARTIFACTORY_HOMEFolder) says the ARTIFACTORY_HOME directory is

```
{user.home}/.artifactory
```

Yet if you install from .deb packages, there is no home directory for the `artifactory` user.

Where is `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME` when installed from packages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Packages

The default configs are located in: `/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default`
Opening that file shows ARTIFACTORY_HOME is `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory`

#### Docker

If using the official artifactory docker container:

`ARTIFACTORY_HOME=/opt/jfrog/artifactory`

Answer (score 0):

On Mac:
it is here

```
ARTIFACTORY_HOME=/usr/local/opt/artifactory/libexec
```